# Is it possible to determine an instance of an NP-hard problem is easy or hard by the optimization?

Tags: optimization, np-hard, iteration

I have an NP-hard problem and an optimization to deal with the problem.

I want to know that is it possible to distinguish between easy and difficult instances of the problem by the parameters of the optimization, like the number of iteration to solve them?

I am not sure that there exists any relation or not. But, I thought that difficult instances need brute force search that may lead to more iterations to find the solution. Therefore, difficult cases need iterations in greater order than easy ones. Note that, I know there exist different algorithms. But we are talking about a given one. It does not matter the algorithm X is faster than Y. We want to compare the number of iterations between easy instance A and hard instance B in a given algorithm X. The comparison will be correct for instances A and B in algorithm Y on a different scale. Consider that the number of iterations is just an assumption and, I don't know what parameter of optimization can make this comparison for instances.

At first, I want to know that is there any relation between optimization's parameters and easy or hard instances.  Then, if yes, what is the valid way to make a comparison?

Comment: The metric I would use is the runtime of an algorithm that solves or approximates the problem Suppose you have such an algorithm that runs in $O(f(n))$, where $n$ is the size of the input. Then you can simply compute $f(n)$.

Comment: @Tyler, But runtime is not independent and may depend on something else on your system. For example, the same case can be run in different runtimes based on your RAM.